# Get an image from a view with translucent navigation bar, but the image has no translucent navigation bar

Tags: ios, image, uinavigationbar

I have a view with translucent navigation bar. And I tried to get an image from it. But the image I got has a solid navigation bar. Any suggestion?

The code I use to get image

```
- (UIImage *)getImage {
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, self.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Try getting a `snapshot` first, and then use `UIGraphicsContext` to render it's image.

Comment: I replaced `[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` with `[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:afterUpdates];` ,and that solved my problem. Thanks.